# <input> elements in ng-repeat don't get focused after editing input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, focus

I'm implementing editable table. I observe the same bug in all of the tutorials on the web. If you have 2 editables, you change one of them. After that you can't focus another one. You have to do two clicks.

Here is one of the tutorials:
http://www.codelord.net/2014/05/10/understanding-angulars-magic-dont-bind-to-primitives/

And this is jsfiddle from it:

[jsfiddle with a bug](http://jsfiddle.net/avivby/ZXmuR/)

This is controller code:

```
<div ng-controller="bookCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="tag in book.tags track by $index">
        <input type="text" ng-model="book.tags[$index]"/>
    </div>

    My tags are <b>really</b>: {{ book.tags }}
</div>
```

Please note, that **track by** doesn't help here. All three samples from the tutorial (and many others) have this problem.

How can I fix this?

UPDATE: I am on chrome 47, also observe the same in firefox.
UPDATE 2: I've uploaded [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOl49kRUddM&feature=youtu.be), bug doesn't reproduce with 100% but the last mouse click indicates the problem. My mouse works fine!

Comment: I really don't know what is wrong. I try your fiddle but I can edit one input and focus the following one. Browser issue?

Comment: Are these model changes happening in the browser or in code (controller)?

Comment: 1) Updated browser info. 2) by model change I mean editing input contents.

Comment: Not seeing the problem on IE11 or Chrome 47

Comment: @jbrown take a look at the video, plz. my mouse is functional!

Comment: So you want the text selected when the element has focus?  See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="bookCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="tag in book.tags track by $index">
    <input type="text" ng-model="book.tags[$index]" ng-focus="selectText($event)" />
  </div>

  My tags are <b>really</b>: {{ book.tags }}
</div>
```

Add this to Controller:

```
    $scope.selectText = function($event) {
      $event.target.select();
    };
```

Comment: Ok so either I don't understand the problem or it's something wrong in your environment.

Comment: can you reproduce the issue when you do lots of clicks?

Comment: No, I can't reproduce it.  Is my assumption correct that you want the text selected when the element receives focus?

Comment: No. I want my cursor to get inside input. I click, but cursor is still in previous input. I click, but nothing happens, check last two clicks in the video. I tried your approach with .focus() instead of .select(), but it doesn't help also.

Comment: No, I can't reproduce that at all

Comment: may be this is OS-specific? I am on windows7

Comment: Maybe but that seems like a reach.  I'm on 8.1

Comment: Have you tried creating your own jsfiddle or plunker?  Maybe try a plunker and see if you get different results.

Comment: I have my own app on localhost and the bug is always there.

Comment: I am able to reproduce even in Linux in virtual box!